# Как задать фон и цвет шрифта части текста в TextView на Андроид используя Html.TagHandler для неподдерживаемых HTML тэгов?

Tags: java, android, android-textview

**Дано:**

Есть `HTML` код, в нём текст, в тексте код, заключённый в тэг `<code>Тут код</code>`.

**Задача:**

Текст внутри тэга должен иметь нужный мне цвет и определённого цвета фон.

**Вопрос:**

Как этого добиться, если учесть, что текст назначается (и должен продолжать назначаться) `TextView` так:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myAwesomeTextWithCode));
```

Comment: Статья обо всех типах `Span` с примерами использования: [Spans, a Powerful Concept](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2014/01/31/spans/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для обработки неподдерживаемых тэгов надо передавать в качестве 3 аргумента метода `Html.fromHtml` экземпляр класса, расширяющего `Html.TagHandler`, в коем и будет происходить обработка всех неподдерживаемых на Android `HTML` тэгов:

```
public class MyHtmlTagHandler implements TagHandler
{        
    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("code"))
        {
            processCode(opening, output);
        }
   }

    private void processCode(boolean opening, Editable output)
    {
        int len = output.length();
        if (opening)
        {
            output.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), len, len, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
            output.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), len, len, Spanned.SPAN_MARK_MARK);
        }
        else
        {
            Object obj = getLast(output, BackgroundColorSpan.class);
            int where = output.getSpanStart(obj);

            output.removeSpan(obj);

            if (where != len)
            {
                output.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), where, len, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                output.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), where, len, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            }
        }
    }

    private static Object getLast(Spanned text, Class<?> kind)
    {
        /*
         * This knows that the last returned object from getSpans()
         * will be the most recently added.
         */
        Object[] objs = text.getSpans(0, text.length(), kind);
        if (objs.length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return objs[objs.length - 1];
    }
}
```

Т.е. теперь вы можете сделать так:

```
String myAwesomeTextWithCode = "<p>некод-некод <code>Тут код</code> опять-не-код</p>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(myAwesomeTextWithCode, null, new MyHtmlTagHandler()));
```