# HTML в ListView

Tags: java, android, html, listview

Доброго времени суток. Имеется html-текст, выводимый в `ListView`. `listView` не воспринимает html теги и отображает текст как есть. Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать, чтобы `listView` отображал текст с учетом тегов? Спасибо.

Нашел на просторах инета такой вариант решения:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= ArrayAdapter<String>(SearchByFood.this, R.layout.new_list_view, arr_sort){
     public Object getItem(int position)
     {
          return Html.fromHtml(arr_sort.get(position));
     }
};
```

Но у меня тогда подчеркивает `Object` и в логе ошибка:

```
Error:(47, 27) error: getItem(int) cannot override getItem(int) in ArrayAdapter
return type Object is not compatible with String
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in class ArrayAdapter
```

Comment: для отображения `HTML` существует `WebView`. `ListView` Для этого не предназначен.

Answer (score 1):

Отобразить HTML можно в TextView так:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("text <b>bold text</b> more text"));
```

Список поддерживаемых тэгов можно [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463753/17609) посмотреть.

Как сделать поддержку других тэгов смотрите [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/484615/17609)